# setTimeout behavior with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

It is my understanding that setTimeout() can be used to stop code from executing temporarily, however this doesn't seem to be the case in the following code:

```
...}).done(function recursionLoad(){     
            var timerLoad = setTimeout(function(){


                },3000)

                $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url:'modelBN.xml',
           beforeSend: function(){$('#query-results').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"><p>Loading...</p>'); },
           timeout: 10000,
           error: function(xhr, status, error){...
```

So what happens is the AJAX call get made immediately instead being delayed for 3 seconds. Am I just using setTimeout incorrectly or is there something about AJAX that prevents it from working?  Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` will call the function you pass to it (in the first argument) after the time you specify in the second argument.

It is not a `sleep` function, and it won't block other code from running.

If you want to run your call to `$.ajax` after the time has elapsed, then  you need to do so from the function you pass to `setTimeout` (as opposed to calling `setTimeout` (with a function that will do nothing after 3 seconds) and then immediately calling `$.ajax`).

Comment: Great. Thanks. My only problem is that I may have to use setTimeout more than once.  So I am waiting for a file and just checking for it periodically. If I don't find the file I call setTimeout again from within the ajax call.